# using react-redux connect with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm trying to use React-redux connect with typescript. I'm confused in using the `connect` with `withRouter`.

I'm trying to use it like,

```
withRouter<any>(connect<{},ComponentProps,{}>(
    matchStateToProps, 
    matchDispatchToProps
)(Component));
```

When trying to pass property `productList` it throws,

> TS2339: Property 'productList' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes, ComponentState>> & Rea...

But in another component,

```
withRouter<any>(connect<{}, ComponentProps, {}>(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component));
```

Does work just fine. 
`ComponentProps` contains all the properties of component. (including `stateProps`, `dispatchProps`, `RouteProps`, & own props).

How to use `connect` in typescript with react's `withRouter`? What should I pass as props for `withRouter` & `connect`?

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ Why not? What happened?

Comment: @underscore_d I don't have a clue. To be honest, I don't know whether any of the above approach is correct.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. There may be another error that has to do with some property 'productList', but I cannot see any of the code for that.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way:

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
```

then:

```
export default compose<React.ComponentClass>(
  withRouter,
  connect<IMapStateToProps, IMapDispatchToProps, IConnectedRouterProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
      fetchComponentData
    },
  ),
)(Component);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trouble I was able to get this to work!

```
// assuming all these interfaces are well defined somewhere.
type MyComponentProps = OwnProps & ComposeProps & StateProps & DispatchProps;

// the secret sauce, need to define a class constructor to pass to compose
interface MyComponentClass<MyComponentProps> extends React.ComponentClass {
  new (props: MyComponentProps): React.Component<MyComponentProps>;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps> {
  ...
}

export default compose<MyComponentClass<MyComponentProps>>(
  withSomeHOC(),
  connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(MyComponent);
```

The above will allow you to import the composed component and maintain type safety!